# Should I buy health insurance before visa appointment for German National Visa

Tags: visa, working-visas, germany, indian-citizens

I have an appointment at German Embassy for German National Visa this Monday. The purpose is a new employment (Got a job in Germany). I was going through the [checklist](https://india.diplo.de/blob/1841710/29cf3a557cf18bbd369e111e3e3688c6/employment-data.pdf) and found out about the travel health insurance -

> Certificate about compulsory health insurance (Gesetzliche
>   Krankenversicherung) from German employer valid from date of
>   employment. Please note: If not already included in the compulsory
>   health insurance a separate travel health insurance has to be
>   presented for the time frame from arrival in Germany until beginning
>   of employment (see below)

Furthermore, it mentions -

> In case of visa approval, you will be requested to present a travel
>   health insurance (Kindly refer to www.india.diplo.de/visa to find out
>   about the travel health insurances accepted).

So, I am assuming that the travel health insurance is not required at the time of application, but only after approval. Is that correct?

I already have a confirmation from my new employer which mentions the following text -

> This letter is to confirm that we will ensure that our prospective
>   employee , born on  will obtain health
>   insurance in Germany and  is taking care of registering
>   the employee for the health insurance.

I confirmed with the HR and she says I still have to buy a health insurance. She doesn't know whether it's before or after appointment/approval.

So should I go at the embassy with a confirmed travel health insurance or not?

Comment: That means even if its in the checklist we dont have to submit certificate about health insurance during the application. Certificate has to be submitted once your visa gets approved. Is my understanding correct ?

Comment: @ShivaGautam You have to submit the employer certification mentioning that they'll take care of the health insurance during the application process. You can choose the health insurance later when you come to Germany. The *Travel health Insurance* confirmation needs to be submitted after the visa is approved and you have to submit it with the passport.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I checked with the Embassy, as well as the visa officer at the time of my appointment at the embassy that health insurance is required at the time of approval only.

**Update:**

I have received my visa stamped today. In the first appointment, health insurance is not required. They return the passport to you with a stamp on it to mark that you applied and reserve a spot on the pages. When the visa gets approved, they ask to bring health insurance confirmation along with the Passport. After a week the passport, I have received the visa stamped on  the marked page.

Comment: Did your employer share the insurance details (or insurance doc) to you after your VISA approval? were they couriered to you after approval or email?

Comment: @BhanuHoysala Yeah they sent me a letter mentioning that they'll take care of the health insurance when I'll arrive in Germany. However, I had to buy the travel insurance separately.

Comment: do I need to Visit consulate twice for Visa Processing , I live far away from consulate.

Comment: @ETL_Devs For me I had to visit the embassy only once and the next time I instead visited the VFS to submit the passport and then another time to collect the passport. It was 3 visits in total. I am not sure if VFS operates in your country or not, or if your locality has any VFS centre or not but it's at least 3 visits.

Comment: Is the letter mentioning about health insurance sent via physical mail? Or is email sufficient?

Answer (score 1):

Travel health insurance is required, your employer has confirmed that they will ensure that they will deal with the registration of your health insurance.

They will also register you for taxes, including church tax.

They will ask you which church and if it belongs to the church tax system an extra tax is deducted.

'Church of England' is one that does **not** belong to it and of course **none** is also a valid answer.

Comment: Given that the question is tagged "indian-citizen", it is *very* unlikely that the OP is a member of the CoE (they might be a member of the Anglican Communion, but even that is not very likely).

Comment: The point was a sample of a church that does not participate in the church tax system PLUS **none** as a valid answer. There may be many others for which this information, with practical sample, will be useful. I know Church of England to be true, which prefer to quote rather than guessing.

Comment: You statement is not only irrelevant but wrong. The Anglian Church of India has 500.000 members https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anglican_Church_of_India

Comment: 1. The Anglican Church of India is not The Church of England.  2.  500,000 out of 1,000,000,000 is 1 in 2000 - which is pretty much what I meant by "not very likely".

Comment: It does't matter, since it is 2 sample of truthful answers which will result that the person will not be liable for the church tax. Many foreigners write only protestant (instead of a specific church name) and must pay the tax to the German luther church (protestent) without being a member of it. Once in, it is very hard to get out. Thus the information with 2 pratical samples for peaple who often do not know that such a tax exist. Do you really believe the readers are so stupid not to know that they should replace CoE with their own religion? Sorry, but I believe your comments are irrelevant

Comment: Well, I am an atheist and never been a christian, so no church tax is applied to me.  Confirmation of registration of health insurance by employer is required though.

Comment: Then **none** would be the answer for you, which was my reason to give 2 samples to make it clear for most situations.

Answer (score 1):

I had my appointment early in November 2022 at VFS Chennai for an EU Blue Card in Germany.

I submitted three documents for health insurance:

- A letter from my employer (on their letterhead) stating that insurance will be covered by them
- A travel health insurance covering from the date of entry (as specified in the visa application form) for 120 days
- I applied for health insurance with a [public health insurance provider in Germany](https://allaboutberlin.com/guides/german-health-insurance#private-health-insurance) (in my case, TK). This took 3-4 days to get. After this, I received a versicherungbescheinigung (health insurance number). I submitted a copy of this with the visa.

I received an approved visa with no further enquiries 15 calendar days later.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to submit the health insurance papers and your flight tickets when you receive the mail that you need to submit your passport for visa stamping. They dodnt need the travel insurance on the first appointment. On your first appointment they will check all your documents and you will submit your application.