# Is compulsory health insurance (Gesetzliche Krankenversicherung) mandatory for German Employment Visa?

Tags: working-visas, germany, health-insurance

I will be applying for German Employment Visa within few weeks. I have received the signed contract from my employer but I dont have this document "Certificate about compulsory health insurance (Gesetzliche Krankenversicherung) from German employer valid from date of employment". Is this document mandatory for Visa application ? What others documents can be provided instead of this ?

Comment: I see this question was asked in 2019. Could you edit your question and talk about how things went?

Answer (score 2):

All German residents must have health insurance, employed or not. If you take up residence in Germany, you must have insurance. However, you must not necessarily have *Gesetzliche* health insurance. Private health insurance is also valid if you qualify for it.

Your employer needs your health insurance details because insurance payments are taken directly from your paycheque. The immigration authorities need a proof of health insurance coverage because it's a legal requirement to live in Germany. In [this thread](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/17253/should-i-buy-health-insurance-before-visa-appointment-for-german-national-visa/17274#17274), one of the answers says that health insurance is also required for your visa.

You might want to read about health insurance in Germany before going forward. [This guide](https://allaboutberlin.com/guides/german-health-insurance) covers most of what you need to know.

Comment: I have a clear concept that health insurance is compulsory in Germany. I was wondering if my Visa will be rejected or not if I don't submit the health insurance  certificate while submitting application for visa ?

Comment: Yes. Health insurance coverage is one of the main requirements, and this is explicitly listed in the required documents on Berlin.de.

Answer (score 0):

no, for the visa appliance is not required, but before you begin to work your employer have to do some paper work and one of this is register the name of your insurance company.. in Germany a part of the insurance is paid by you and the rest by the employer, so you HAVE to have a insurance before you begin to work.

Comment: I also got the same idea as I went through different websites but the embassy  has mentioned this document in the checklist for employment Visa.  This is what got me tensed. Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Without a direct quote from (or link to) this checklist, it is hard to say exactly what is being asked for.

If you have worked before in Germany then you would be a member of a **Krankenkasse** (Health insurance provider)

- proof of that membership, if you have it already, is probably what they are asking for

If you have never worked before, this you must **join** one.

Which one and what type

- **Gesetzliche** or **Privat** insurer

  - when in doubt choose **Gesetzliche**

    - once registered in a **Privat**, you can **never** switch to a **Gesetzliche**

A general overview (in German) about how this is done can be found here (I assume this is a neutral site):

[Ausländer in Deutschland: Die richtige Krankenkasse finden](https://www.krankenkassen.de/meine-krankenkasse/krankenversicherung-eu/krankenkasse-anmeldung/)

> **Register in time with the health insurance**
>
> If foreigners work in Germany, their company will **ask them for their health insurance before they start working**.  You can register with the health insurance company as soon as you know who your employer will be.  <strike>Even foreigners without work in Germany can become a member of the statutory health insurance in many cases.</strike>  EU citizens and other foreigners should therefore obtain early application documents for the health insurance.  The necessary confirmations about the pre-insurance can be submitted later.

---

Since your employer is known (you have a contract) you can join one now, effective on your first day of work.

So the process would be to find a Krankenkasse that suits your needs.

The following deals with **Gesetzliche** only

#### Backround

In the past, a Krankenkasse was often specific to a profession, searving the needs of that profession.
This is no longer the case.

There are price differences (expressed in Procentage) between them, but that does not necessarily mean that they are worse when cheaper (almost the opposite can be claimed).

In general, you get a card and use it with a doctor and that is it.
Some things, however, must be applied for beforhand and only a certain amount is taken over (Kostenplan).

Extensive dentistry work is such a case. A good Krankenkassen makes this process very simple, some are a burocratic nightmare.
Tips from colleagues can be very helpful in choosing.

<strike>Important is to know that you can change your Krankenkasse at any time, effective within (mostly) a 3 month period.</strike>

Changing a Krankenkassen is only possible after 18 months and notice is then 2 full months (31st August to 1st November) in most cases.

If english is you main language, finding a local Krankenkasse with good English support would also be an important factor.

---

The site above offers a list, listed by Cities:

- [Krankenkassen vor Ort](https://www.krankenkassen.de/krankenkassen-vor-ort/)

  - [Krankenkassen Berlin](https://www.krankenkassen.de/krankenkassen-vor-ort/berlin/)

After selecting a city, you will get a list of those that have offices in that city plus a map showing where the offices are.

- a link is offered with more information about the Krankenkasse

  - note the names of those that interest you and visit their main site

Often an online application is possible at the original Krankenkasse site.

- supplying the name and address of your employer and start date will probably be required

  - possibly your address in Germany may be a requirement, but maybe it maybe that can be supplied later after arrival

The end of the process will be in some form of a membership certificate.

This is what is being asked for in your question.

You should also send this to your employer, insuring that you will be insured from day 1.

- you employer will send the membership fee (Krankenkasse Beitrag) directly to the Krankenkasse.

Comment: It was such a great explanation. But my main concern is whether I should submit that document along with other documents or not for the visa application. The checklist is here : https://kathmandu.diplo.de/blob/1788862/89eedff46cda8bb41ee56879db6e4ab6/employment-visa-checklist-data.pdf

Comment: @ShivaGautam Since you're not  a member of a Krankenkassen yet, you can't. See another answer of a similar case: https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/17274/17166  Send the form to your employer and ask them to write something.

Comment: That means I don't need the health insurance for now but once my visa gets approved the embassy will ask me to submit it. Is that right ?

Comment: @ShivaGautam For travel insurance yes. For the Krankenkasse ask them during the interview. To be frank I find this requirement strange since it is common to join a Krankenkassen after arrival and that the employer makes sure its done properly.