# Health Insurance and Intended Place of Stay For Research Assistant (PhD) Student in Germany

Tags: germany, indian-citizens

My friend, an Indian national, recently completed a Masters level course in France and has been admitted by a German institute for a PhD program. His contract is of 'wissenschaftlicher Mitarbeiter', and will receive a salary and make state contributions. He is applying for a type D visa using with this [form](https://allemagneenfrance.diplo.de/blob/2250878/f9342033f2933dc05da54151efe283db/00-visa-antrag--dtsch--engl--datei-data.pdf) and this [document checklist](https://allemagneenfrance.diplo.de/blob/2108244/e1a0f256e4f2c57f1d57590aece405cc/03-03-wissenschaftler-datei-data.pdf), and he will submit his application to the Consulate of Germany in Paris.

1. Is it correct to select "Employment" in question 9 of the form despite this being PhD studies?
2. The form asks in question 6, "Vorgesehener Aufenthaltsort in der Bundesrepublik Deutschland/Intended place of stay in Germany". As he has not availed accommodation in Germany yet, is it sufficient to mention the name and postcode of the institute?
3. The last item in the document checklist asks for insurance, but footnote 2 specifies that it is not required for applicants who pay social security contributions. Is it correct to infer that he does not require health insurance, or does he need to purchase private health insurance?
4. Question 12 of the form asks for the intended duration of stay in Germany. Is it correct to enter the start and end date of the contract considering that PhDs may last longer than initially expected? Would it be acceptable to enter the start date as being a few days prior to the start date of the contract?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- 1) yes, **wissenschaftlicher Mitarbeiter** (scientific Assistant) is an **employment** activity
- 2) yes, City and Postal Code of the Institution is fine (they want to know which Foreigners Office will be responsible for you, which that information supplies)
- 3) yes, but they must be covered by insurance between entry until the first day of employment, but the insurance need not exist at the date of application.
- 4a) A realistic day of arrival should be given, the assumption being you need time to get oriented and find a place to stay (you may not enter until the given start date)
- 4b) End of contract should be given, which then can be extended as needed

The person should inform themselves about the possibilities of health insurance until the first day of employment

- would their present French insurance cover that while inside Germany?

This may be asked during any interview. Proof may be required after the visa has been granted.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Just to clarify, the answer to 3 means that he is covered by state health insurance from the start of his contract, but needs health insurance for any time he may spend in Germany prior to the start date of the contract, right?

Comment: @SgrA yes. I believe a simple travel insurance is deemed suitable.

Comment: @SgrA lopok also at this information about choosing a Health insurance https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/19246/17166